# closing jframes current window and not the entire application

Tags: java

i need to close my applications current window without switching off the entire application my code is as follows to set a window visible but it closes all the windows whatever are currently open when i click on the right upper corner red cross button

```
 private void lb_helpMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
          new Reports().setVisible(true);
    }          
private void lb_certMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        new ChooseCert().setVisible(true);
    } 
private void lb_reportMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        new Reports().setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Try frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: It sounds like EXIT_ON_CLOSE is the problem, not the solution.  Change any lines which set the default close operation to EXIT_ON_CLOSE to use DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void closeWindow() {
    WindowEvent wev = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(wev);

    setVisible(false);
    dispose();
}

public void closeApplication() {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

After that just call the appropriate methods.